# Unable to connect to mssql server from PHP in Centos 6

Tags: php, sql-server, centos6

I have installed php-mssql package in Centos 6 for MSSql connection. I want to connect remote MSSql server from PHP 5.3.3.

**My code:**

```
$link = mssql_connect("192.168.*.*", 'username', 'password') or die ("Could not connect to database: ".mssql_get_last_message());
if (!$link) {
        die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');
}
```

But I am getting below **error**,

```
Warning: mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server: 192.168.*.* in /var/www/html/test.php on line 22
```

If I use through `freetds`, it is working.

```
tsql -S192.168.*.* -Uusername -Ppassword
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this and set network connect is 1 i.e on

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```

Comment: if you got solution make it green tick its useful to future user reference @selvan

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are being blocked by SELinux. If I'm right, executing these commands should solve your problem:

```
$ sudo -i 
  Password: 
# setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
# setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```